# AutomaticLaTeXPlugin + MacVim on OSX Lion

Tags: vim

I am desparatly trying to get the [AutomaticLaTeXPlugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) to work with MacVim. I previously worked with Latex-Suite but i really like the autocompilation, progressbar .. that AutomaticLaTeXPlugin seems to offer.

I fullfill all the [Requirements](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/requirements.shtml). I am using [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)+[Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) and have installed the plugin in my `~/.janus`directory. Some things work (like `:TOC`, `:help atp`) but the compilation is not fully working.

Doing `:TEX` and nothing changes (no statusbar, nor any compilation). Doing `:PID`says `[ATP:] lualatex is not running`. The only compilation aspects that do work is running `:Latexmk`or pressing `F5`(which results in the whole window showing me the compilation log file).

How can i get the automatic compilation, progressbar, `:TEX`commands to work?

My current `~\.atprc.vim`: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/ExFsJ3Er)

Comment: Have you solve the problem yet?

Comment: @bioslime, what is the status of this question? Have you found a solution?